# DCC Error, uPriority.pas(34): E2004 Identifier redeclared: 'frmPri'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Really need some help here, probably a simple solution, not a expert programmer by any means!!

Now I haven't used frmPri anywhere else in any of my units in my project so I'm not sure why this is happening??

[image]

Thanks guys,
C

Comment: You are implemeting a class method, so you should declare it that way: TFrmPriority.DisplayPatientData. You can also press ctrl+shift+c and the IDE will do this automatically.

Comment: Please post code and not screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class methods should start with that name of the class (i.e. TfrmPriority). Not frmPrio as this is the name of the variable.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know why I didn't see this, I've done it correctly in my other units - must be tired! Cheers boss